# sysconfig cflags and ldflags does not link python into a C executable

Tags: python

So I am looking for a cross platform way to compile, and link Python into a C executable. I am following this page as a guide, such as with this example listed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding). One problem is, the last section recommends using `sysconfig` or looking for the `python*-config` executable installed next to the interpreter to get the cflags and ldflags used to embed Python. However, those do not work

On my mac, the CFLAGS are `"-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk"` and the LDFLAGS are `"-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk"` . But using those with the documentation's example does not work, and always results in include errors. Even if i tweak it and add the `-I` option for where Python's include dir is, it gives linker errors:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 test.c -o test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyMem_RawFree", referenced from:
      _main in test-75ae4e.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _main in test-75ae4e.o
  "_Py_DecodeLocale", referenced from:
      _main in test-75ae4e.o
  "_Py_FinalizeEx", referenced from:
      _main in test-75ae4e.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in test-75ae4e.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      _main in test-75ae4e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

My question here is, how does one reliably determine the flags to link / include python into a C executable ? and how can those be determined on msvc, gcc, or clang?

Answer (score 1):

After using the `-I` to include the directory that contains `Python.h` and `-L` to include the directory that contains `libpython3.9.a`, you need to tell the compiler to actually use the library file (it will not by default load every shared library in the linked paths, that's dangerous).

You do that by including the library flag `-lpython3.9`, which should be after `-L/path/to/python/lib`, or just right before `test.c` in your example. For ease, I'd suggest using the command to compile a shared library in C that can be imported in Python

```bash
cc -shared -fPIC -O3 $(python3-config --includes) $(python3-config --ldflags) -lpython3.9 "test.c" -o "test.so"
```

In order the arguments mean:

- `-shared` compile a shared library (will ensure that all symbols / functions are resolved);
- `-fPIC` generate position independent code, that is the library contents are not contingent on the location at which the library is in the file system;
- `-O3` turn on the most aggressive optimization, usually we are compiling C libraries for their speed, so this is generally desirable;
- `$(python3-config --includes)` this expands out as a shell command to have all the appropriate include commands `-I<include-dir>`;
- `$(python3-config --ldflags)` this expands out as a shell command to have all the appropriate linked library folders `-L<link-lib-dir>`;
- `-lpython3.9` tells the compiler to look for a library / shared object file named `libpython3.9.a` or `libpython3.9.dylib` or similar, which it will find because of the the `ldflags` expansion above;
   ☝️ **THIS IS THE PART YOU WERE MISSING**; and
- `-o test.so` is naming the output file in a POSIX way (Windows will not like this, I don't think).

Hopefully that helps! I got stuck on the same problem and didn't find your question here until afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this is possible with the `--embed` option. Although this is not documented in the Python documentation, here's an example on MacOS

```
% /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3-config --cflags --embed
-I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
% /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3-config --ldflags --embed
-L/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin -lpython3.9 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

And then putting it altogether to compile and link a C executable with Python

```
gcc -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin -lpython3.9 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation test.c -o test
```